# qt How to put my function into a thread

Tags: multithreading, qt

I'm a QT newbie. I have a class extend from widget like:

```
class myclass: public Qwidget
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
  void myfunction(int);
slots:
  void myslot(int)
  {
    //Here I want to put myfunction into a thread
  }
  ...
}
```

I don't know how to do it. Please help me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add a `QThread` member then in `myslot` move your object to the thread and run the function.

```
class myclass: public Qwidget
{
   QThread thread;
public:
slots:
  void myfunction(int); //changed to slot
  void myslot(int)
  {
    //Here I want to put myfunction into a thread
    moveToThread(&thread);
    connect(&thread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(myfunction())); //cant have parameter sorry, when using connect
    thread.start();
  }
  ...
}
```

My answer is basically the same as from this post: [Is it possible to implement polling with QThread without subclassing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368473/is-it-possible-to-implement-polling-with-qthread-without-subclassing-it)

Comment: Qt doc says that : moveToThread changes the thread affinity for this object and its children. The object cannot be moved if it has a parent. He has a widget and it probably has a parent. You have to be careful here about the parent of this widget. You may not move it at all ! What do you think ?

Comment: @orcunc: I need to change its children to solve a problem in a new thread without affect main process. After that, it will return value to main thread. That's my idea. Do you have any idea to solve that problem? Please let me know.

Comment: If I needed to run a long task without blocking my UI and then return the result back to my UI I would use QFutureWatcher. Read it http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfuturewatcher.html. Examine the example. It is really easy to use. Don't mess with parents and anything else ! See another example here http://codejourneys.blogspot.com/2008/06/qt-simple-example-of-use-of.html This is what I would do. Use QtConcurrent package!

Comment: Since this is a popular result for qt+threading, this should be tossed into the bowl: http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: Really? I don't get why  would I want to move entire object to that thread. The function i wanted to run in thread will run in that thread  but  all the other functions(not necessarily needed to run on another thread) in the object are also going to run on that that thread.

Comment: When I do this, I get an error:
``QObject::moveToThread: Widgets cannot be moved to a new thread``

Why is that when I am moving the Thread object to a new thread?

Comment: You absolutely **cannot move a QWidget to a non-GUI thread** (that is, anything but the main QApplication event loop).  https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread

Answer (score 5):

Your question is very broad . Please find some alternatives that could be beneficial to you :

- If you want to use signal/slot mechanism and execute your slot within a thread context you can use [moveToThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) method to move your object into a thread (or create it directly within the run method of QThread) and execute your slot within that thread's context. But Qt Docs says that

> The object cannot be moved if it has a
>   parent.

Since your object is a widget, I assume that it will have a parent.

So it is **unlikely** that this method will be useful for you.

- Another alternative is using [QtConcurrent::run()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html) This allows a method to be executed by another thread. However this way you can not use signal/slot mechanism. Since you declared your method as a slot. I assumed that you want to use this mechanism. If you don't **care** then this method will be useful for you.
- Finally you can create a [QThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) subclass within your slot and execute whatever your like there.

This is all I could think of.

I hope this helps.